# TCP ThreadPool (Address already in use)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, threadpool

Good Day,

I have implemented a threadpool, which takes in a Runnable Object. Basically, I am building a simple server implementation that has to handle requests. The code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Assign your no. of thread to create 
    int noOfProcess = 5; 
    // Assign your own thread pool size
    int poolMaxSize = 2;

    // Creating Threadpool with the thread size given above
    MyThreadPool threadPool = new MyThreadPool(poolMaxSize);
    // Creating threadpool Object
    ThreadPoolTester obj = new ThreadPoolTester();

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcess; i++) {
        threadPool.process(obj.startProcess(i));
    }

    // Finally waiting for all thread to complete its process
    threadPool.join();
}

private Runnable startProcess(final int taskID) {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Task " + taskID + ": start");

            ServerSocket server;
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(8080);
                while (true) {
                    final Socket connection = server.accept();
                    handle(connection);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Task " + taskID + ": end");
        }
    };
}
```

Basically, this works as it should when I have only 1 thread inserted into the threadpool. However, once I have two or more, there is a bind exception thrown.

What I want to know is, what is the correct way to handle this? How do servers normally do this? Do you just capture the exception, and keep looping until a thread completes the task? Is there a way to make the thread sleep until it can take in an accept?

How would I have 5 clients make a request at the same time, and what would be the actual workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line creates the `ServerSocket` and binds it to port `8080`:

```
server = new ServerSocket(8080);
```

As you do this inside your `Runnable`, you're creating multiple ServerSockets for the same port if you use multiple threads! That's why you get the exception - the port is already in use.

You do not need to create multiple `ServerSockets` if you want to handle multiple client requests in parallel. Use the thread pool inside your `handle` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    // Creating Threadpool with the thread size given above
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        handleAsync(executor, socket);
    }
}

private void handleAsync(ExecutorService executor, final Socket socket) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handle(socket);
        }
    };
}

private static void handle(Socket socket) {
    // TODO: communicate with client using socket
}
```

See also [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for another server example.
Another turial is [Thread Pooled Server](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/thread-pooled-server.html) from [Jakob Jenkov](http://jenkov.com/).

Comment: Got it. Only need to create Server Socket once. Thanks!